# Is it true that A $\models$ B iff A $\rightarrow$ B?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Is it true that A $\models$ B iff A $\rightarrow$ B?

I understand that A, A $\rightarrow$ B $\models$ B, so I just want to see if the aforementioned is also true, to confirm my understanding.

Comment: Written that way, it is wrong: it must be  $A ⊨ B$ iff $A → B$ is a tautology.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! What about "A⊨B iff A→B is true"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A material implication $A \rightarrow B$ could be true in a world where both $A$ and $B$ are true, but if there is another world where $A$ is true and $B$ is false, then we don't have $A \vDash B$

It is in fact a little weird to compare these two statements: $A \to B$ is a *logic* statement whose truth is to be evaluated with regard to some specific world, whereas $A \vDash B$ is a *meta-logic* statement whose truth is not relative to some specific world but rather ends up making a claim about all possible worlds.

Now, as Parcly Taxel points out, we can make a meta-logic statement about $A \to B$ by saying something like "$A \to B$ is a tautology" ... and *now* the if and only if does hold:

$A \vDash B$ iff $A \to B$ is a tautology

Comment: Thanks! What about "A⊨B  iff A→B is true"?

Comment: @PeterG That's effectively how I read " $A \models$ B iff A $\rightarrow$ B?", so it has the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

$A\to B$ does not have a truth value by itself. The descriptor "is a tautology" must be added to $A\to B$ in order for the question statement to be true.

When that modified statement holds for some $A$ and $B$, we may shorten it to $\models A\to B$.

Comment: So the answer is no. Because it should be  A ⊨ B iff $\models$ A → B?

Comment: @PeterG iff can be reversed

Comment: I see, so the extra $\models$ is meaningless here since iff already means A $\rightarrow$ B is a tautology.

Comment: @peterg yes, indeed.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel - I don't agree with your comment. A formula $A \to B$, alone, does not have any meaning or any "meta-theoretic" content. If you want to say that $A \to B$ is a tautology, then the usual notation is $\models A \to B$, as MauroALLEGRANZA correctly says in his comment.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco it is implied when I write $A\to B$ without anything else that it is deemed a tautology.

Comment: @RuggieroRilievi Edited. Please delete your comment.